# How to change the color of the selected tab in the TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, tabcontrol

I am implementing a `TabControl` for a dialog box in WPF. The color of the selected tab (mouse-down) is white by default. I want to change the color of that selected tab to the color of hover (when I hover over a tab, the color of the tab changes to an Office-blue-gradient, which is what I want the color of the selected tab to be on mouse-click).

How can I do that?

This piece of code does not work:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFDFDFD"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected "  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="SlateGray"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note: I also tried IsMouseCaptured event for the trigger property. Still does not work.

Comment: You can create a css class for this and set the mouse-down property to whatever you want... or you can go into the default css you have loaded for your site and modify it there. The first approach is typically better unless you want the entire site to behave like this.

Comment: CSS in WPF?  I think you didnt read the question

Comment: Show some code, what you've tried. Lest you get a CSS answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright...after hours of trying, I have realized that the TabItem selection behaviour is defined at the Template level. So, if I wana change the backgrnd color, I do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                                            CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                                            Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
                                </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```