# Change color of tabitem for multiple tabcontrols

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use two tabcontrols in my project. How can I change color for the tabitem which tabcontrol is currently active/focused?
Here is the xaml sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl x:Name="First" Grid.Column="0">
        <TabItem Header="Test1" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
            <Label>Text</Label>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test2" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
            <Label>Text</Label>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <TabControl x:Name="Second" Grid.Column="1">
        <TabItem Header="Test1" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
            <Label>Text</Label>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test2" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
            <Label>Text</Label>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

It should looks like
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the color of the selected tab in the TabControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470918/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-selected-tab-in-the-tabcontrol)

Comment: I tried it. But I have few tacontrols and it changes color for all selected tabitems.

Comment: it will do, because it's setting the style for that particular type, if you want to apply it selectively give the style a key and then apply it to each tabcontrol you want to have the behaviour. If you want a different selected tab colour for each tabcontrol then you probably want to go down the route of a custom control.

Comment: Thank for the answers. But, the main issue its, to make selected tabitem highlighted only for focused/active tabcontrol, but nothighlited another one selecteditem at unfocused/notactive tabcontrol

Comment: You can do that using the triggers in the template as well, there are properties for determining whether an item has focus that you can bind to. I suggest doing a bit more research! Maybe edit the question to be a bit clearer on the actual problem as well.

Comment: Thanks! You give me a good thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed your labels to Textboxes to demonstrate the needed behavior and changed the trigger property to IsKeyboardFocusWithin.

Here you go:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                                            CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                                            Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
                                </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Loaded="MainGrid_Loaded">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl x:Name="First" Grid.Column="0">
            <TabItem Header="Test1" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
                <TextBox>Replace this text</TextBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Test2" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
                <TextBox>Replace this text</TextBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <TabControl x:Name="Second" Grid.Column="1">
            <TabItem Header="Test1" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
                <TextBox>Replace this text</TextBox>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Test2" Margin="-2,-2,-2,0.2" Width="44" >
                <TextBox>Replace this text</TextBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not exactly what I need. You use 'IsFocused' for a tabItem control, but I need to highlite tabItem after tabcontrol ot within element got focused without any reference to the element.

Comment: If you execute the sample, it behaves exactly as your "It should look like" in your request. What do you mean by "I need to highlite tabItem after tabcontrol ot within element got focused without any reference to the element."? 
Can you perhaps provide a larger block of XAML where you have implemented the style as I indicated, so that I can see it not working?

Comment: Your code is working good. I mean, tab must be highlighted, for example, if i click on label at tabcontrol area or, maybe, it could be textblock or some another control.

Comment: I see. Try it now with the edited version. Using IsKeyboardFocusWithin should fix your issue, though without seeing the real contents of your TabItems I can't be certain.

Comment: If the above edit meets your described need, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!