# WPF TabControl selected item color change from back code

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'm quite new in C# and WPF so please forgive in case of stupid questions :-).
**I would like to change dynamically the selected tab color property from the back code.**
I've found few solutions but only for static color change.
Dynamic color change of non-selected tab is done. Please see the code:

XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabSections" Margin="0,400,0,20" Width="1348" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible" TabStripPlacement="Top" Cursor="Hand" SelectionChanged="tabSections_SelectionChanged">
    <TabControl.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF464646" Opacity="1"/>
    </TabControl.Background>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect1"  Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 1">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect2" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 2">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect3" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 3">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect4" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 4">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect5" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 5">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect6" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 6">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect7" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 7">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabSect8" Width="168" Height="30" Header="Section 8">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

C#:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < SectionCount; i++)
    {
        if (TabsColors[i])
        {
            TabBrushes[i] = Brushes.Orange;
        }
        else
        {
            TabBrushes[i] = Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
    }
    for (int j = SectionCount; j < 8; j++)
    {
        TabBrushes[j] = Brushes.DarkGray;
    }
    tabSect1.Background = TabBrushes[0];
    tabSect2.Background = TabBrushes[1];
    tabSect3.Background = TabBrushes[2];
    tabSect4.Background = TabBrushes[3];
    tabSect5.Background = TabBrushes[4];
    tabSect6.Background = TabBrushes[5];
    tabSect7.Background = TabBrushes[6];
    tabSect8.Background = TabBrushes[7];
```

Thank you for help in advance. Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you please clarify the difference between a "static color change" and "dynamic color change"?

Comment: Static is when declared as one color f.eg. red is when tab is selected, the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470918/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-selected-tab-in-the-tabcontrol

Comment: I mean dynamic by having possibility to set the selectedtab color for different situations, sometimes dark orange, sometimes dark green as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the selected item of a `Selector` control by referencing its `SelectedItem` property.

To use a `Style`, simply reference the `Brush` as a dynamic resource and change it from e.g., your code-behind:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedItemBackgroundBrush"
                     Color="Red" /> 

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Margin="0,0,-4,0"
                    CornerRadius="2,12,0,0"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
            </Border>
            
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                       Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="LightGray" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                       Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                        Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{DynamicResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
this.Resources["SelectedItemBackgroundBrush"] = Brushes.GreenYellow;
```

When you need to acces each element of a collection, you should never access it explicitly. Rather would you iterate over the collection:

```cs
for (int tabItemIndex = 0; tabItemIndex < this.tabSections.Items.Count; tabItemindex++)
{
  var tabItem = this.tabSections.Items[tabItemIndex] as TabItem;
  tabItem.Background = tabItem.IsSelected
    ? Brushes.Red
    : this.TabBrushes[tabItemIndex];
}

// Alternative way to change the color of the selected item
var selectedTabItem = this.tabSections.SelectedItem as TabItem;
selectedTabItem.Background = this.TabBrushes[tabItemIndex];
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me accessing TabItems. Now it looks more decent.

Comment: Regarding the Style, I'ts working but unfortunately blocks background color change in the back code. The items are gray even if I change the tabItem.Background. When I delete the Page.Resource from XAML, the tabItem.Background color change is possible.

Comment: In the dependency property system of WPF is something called "value precedence" ([Dependency property precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0#dependency-property-precedence-list)): setting a value locally always overrides the values that come from a Trigger. I have modified the for-loop very slightly to meet you requirements. In your case you must then remove the trigger from the Style (to avoid the precedence conflict).

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to thank you @BionicCode for help.

The mistake I've made from the beginning was the trigger declaration order in XAML.

The below example first declares selected tab property, then enabled tab property which overwrites, so the selected property have no chance to be seen.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Value="LightGray" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FF464646" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource EnabledItemBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The correct order is (selected property after enabled property):

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Value="LightGray" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FF464646" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource EnabledItemBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="UltraLight"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedItemBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Have a good day!